# Disabling power button on Windows CE

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-ce, motorola

I need to prevent the system from suspending. Not because of idle timeout, but because of a power button stroke. Is there a way to hook the power button and cancel the stroke, or a way to enforce the system power that can resist to a power button stroke ?

I don't need to keep the screen lighted, i just need the whole calculation power and the audio (in and out) to be maintained. Also i don't need a cross-platform cross-device solution, i only need this for Windows CE 6.0 using a Motorlla MC3190.

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

As I already stated on another thread, you can't do that unless you have access to the BSP. Motorola may provide some additional APIs to control its devices, I remember that they had some additional tools to configure their behaviour. If they allow you to change purpose of physical keys you may be able to get what you want but usually the sleep button is hard-wired to a CPU pin to allow it to be used as a wake-up source.